# How can i use Mibew Support system on my nginx server?

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I want to use Mibew on my nginx server, but it needs .htaccess with Apache server.
What can I do to use this script on my website?
I'm already try to convert the default .htaccess but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate what you have tried, what errors you get and supply links to the relevant documentation you used. Your question looks like 'It doesn't work, please write a HowTo for me.'

Answer (score 1):

Add to your web site configuration (ex: /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysite.com.conf)

```
location /mibew/ {
    rewrite ^/mibew/$ /mibew/index.php permanent;
    rewrite ^/mibew/install\.php/(.*)$ /mibew/install.php?$1 last;
    rewrite ^/mibew/index\.php/(.*)$ /mibew/index.php?$1 last;
}
```